# Is there a difference between class 1/A stocks and a preferred stock?

Tags: stocks, preferred-stocks

Is there a difference between class A stocks and a preferred stock? or both are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same. "Class A" is a class of *common* stock. Bob mentioned a few differences specific to Class A - here are some others:

- Preferred shares are paid off before common shares in the event of a bankruptcy or liquidation.
- Preferred shares pay a required, fixed dividend; dividends on common shares are optional and can fluctuate.
- Preferred shares are valued based on their dividend, not the value of the company.
- Preferred shares are often *convertible* to common shares, which indirectly benefits preferred shareholders if the value of common shares goes up enough.

Answer (score 1):

Class A shares can be structured in a variety of ways by the company.  Traditional Class A shares are not sold to the public can't be sold, and have more voting rights. Preferred shares do not have voting rights.